# Convert CSV to JSON using python with new headers

Tags: python

I'm new to python and want to convert the following csv file

```
1.0,100.0,303.0,619.0,figure  
338.0,162.0,143.0,423.0,text  
85.0,768.0,554.0,39.0,text  
504.0,164.0,24.0,238.0,subtitle  
120.0,727.0,182.0,13.0,caption  
540.0,165.0,62.0,428.0,title  
614.0,163.0,23.0,133.0,tagline  
317.0,629.0,113.0,113.0,figure  
443.0,629.0,112.0,113.0,figure  
568.0,628.0,121.0,114.0,figure
```

into this format

```json
{
    "record_01": {
        "x": "1.0", 
        "y": "100.0", 
        "width": "303.0", 
        "height": "619.0", 
        "tag": "figure"
    }, 
    "record_02": {
        "x": "338.0", 
        "y": "162.0",
        "width": "143.0", 
        "height": "423.0", 
        "tag": "text"
    }, 
    "record_03": {
        "x": "85.0", 
        "y": "768.0", 
        "width": "554.0", 
        "height": "39.0", 
        "tag": "text"
    }, .... and so on }
```

This is the current code

```py
import csv
import json

def convert_json(csvPath, jsonPath):
    fieldnames = ["x", "y", "width", "height", "tag"]
    with open(csvPath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as csvFile:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, fieldnames)
        data = []
        for rows in csvReader:
            data.append(rows)
    with open(jsonPath, "w", encoding="utf-8") as jsonFile:
        jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

and the output look like this

```json
[
    {
        "x": "1.0",
        "y": "100.0",
        "width": "303.0",
        "height": "619.0",
        "tag": "figure"
    },
    {
        "x": "338.0",
        "y": "162.0",
        "width": "143.0",
        "height": "423.0",
        "tag": "text"
    },
    {
        "x": "85.0",
        "y": "768.0",
        "width": "554.0",
        "height": "39.0",
        "tag": "text"
    }, ..... ]
```

How do I make sure the json file is in curly bracket instead of '[ ]' and add record with number for each entry?
I tried using `data={}` but it didn't work with `data.append(rows)`

Edit: Thanks to the solution and explanation provided by Antonio, I changed my code and it output the expected result.

```
import csv
import json
fieldnames = ["x", "y", "width", "height", "tag"]
def convert_json(csvPath, jsonPath):
    with open(csvPath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as csvFile:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, fieldnames)
        data = {}
        for record, rows in enumerate(csvReader, start=1):
            data.update({"record_{:02d}".format(record): rows})
    with open(jsonPath, "w", encoding="utf-8") as jsonFile:
        json.dump(data, jsonFile, indent=4)


csvPath = "data.csv"
jsonPath = "data.json"
convert_json(csvPath, jsonPath)
```

Comment: You're creating a list instead of a dictionary. Look at Python's `dict` and how to create and fill a dictionary

Comment: If you want an example, create the output file manually, then load it in Python and inspect the resulting data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were creating a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) while you need to use [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). You must declare a dictionary before adding your elements or you could also use dict comprehension to create your dictionary in a more *pythonic* way. To create your records number you can format integer numbers with zero padding. To get the current record number you can use [`enumerate(item)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```py
import csv
import json

def convert_json(csvPath, jsonPath, fieldnames):

    with open(csvPath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as csvFile:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, fieldnames)
        data = {}
        for record, rows in enumerate(csvReader):
            data.update({"record_{:02d}".format(record): rows})
    with open(jsonPath, "w", encoding="utf-8") as jsonFile:
        json.dump(data, jsonFile, indent=4)


convert_json("./data.csv", "json_file.json", ["x", "y", "width", "height", "tag"])
```

Edit:
Version with dict comprehension:

```py
import csv
import json

def convert_json(csvPath, jsonPath, fieldnames):

    with open(csvPath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as csvFile:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, fieldnames)
    
        data = {"record_{:02d}".format(record): rows for record, rows in enumerate(csvReader)}
    with open(jsonPath, "w", encoding="utf-8") as jsonFile:
        json.dump(data, jsonFile, indent=4)

convert_json("./data.csv", "json_file.json", ["x", "y", "width", "height", "tag"])
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it works. What does {:02d} represent in the above code?

Comment: {0:2d} represents a string formatting that was first introduced in Python v2.7 and now is default in Python3. In Python3.6 they introduced formatted string literals aka f-strings. So, you can format your strings however you want {0:2d} print the number in format() with two digits always and is the same as {:02>d}. https://mkaz.blog/code/python-string-format-cookbook/

Answer (score 0):

If your data set is small or fit in the memory, it can be done more easily with pandas as follows:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

DATA_PATH = Path("data").joinpath("data.csv")
WRITE_PATH = Path("data").joinpath("data.json")
COL_SCHEMA = ["x", "y", "width", "height", "tag"]

df = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH, header=None)
df.columns = COL_SCHEMA
df["id"] = "record_" + df.index.astype(str)
df = df.set_index("id")
df.to_json(WRITE_PATH, orient="index", indent=2)
```

Here I have the same data in the `data` directory in a csv file. To make the functions platform-agnostic, I have used `pathlib` now that code can be run in Windows/Unix/Linux with no change. Then I have loaded the data into a data frame and added a new ID column into it. Then I have set that ID column as index of the data frame. I have written the data back into the same directory with proper orientation and for JSON I have use `indent = 2` just for better beautification.

Though, you have to install pandas for that with `pip install pandas` command.

Comment: The following solution also should be much faster than looping over each row. As it takes advantage of BLAS with numpy